# consistency of Neyman Pearson lemma in the case simple vs simple test for exponential families

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Basics, jump to section 2 for the question :

I know that in the case of an exponential family with 1 parameter, meaning the distribution function of the sample variables can be written like :

$$ f_X(t) = \exp( \eta( \theta) T(t) - d( \theta) + S( x) ) $$
if we compare two hypothesis like those :
$$ H_0 : \theta = \theta_0 \text{ vs }  H_1 :\theta = \theta_1$$

Neyman-Pearson lemma tells us that :

> if $\eta$ is increasing we get this test :
>
> $$ \mathbb{1}_{ \sum t_i \geq q_{1 - \alpha}} $$
>
> if $\eta$ is decreasing we get this test :
>
> $$ \mathbb{1}_{ \sum t_i \leq q_{\alpha}} $$
>
> where $q_{\lambda }$ is the solution of this equation  (
>   $\alpha$-quantiles ):
>
> $$ P( \sum t_i \leq q_{\alpha} | H_0 ) = \alpha $$

---

When I first started doing exercices using this formula, i didn't know if I should put constants in the $\eta$ or in the $T$ function. I've succesfully proven that whether you put a positive multiplicative constant in one of those, you get the same result, meaning the two tests functions are the same if you multiply one function by $a$ and the other by $1/a$.

However, i can't do it for $ a = -1$.

I got to this point :

How do you prove the equality of the two following tests :

1. if I'm applying formulas : 
   $$ \mathbb{1}_{ \sum t_i \geq q_{1 - \alpha}} $$
   $$ P( \sum t_i \leq q_{1 -\alpha} | H_0 ) = 1 - \alpha $$
2. if I write $-\eta( \theta) \times - T(t)$ instead :
   $$ \mathbb{1}_{ \sum t_i \geq - q_{\alpha}} $$
   $$ P( \sum t_i \geq - q_{\alpha} | H_0 ) = \alpha $$

I've succesfully done that for a gaussian distribution, but I can't do the general case.

---

disclaimer : I'm still learning basics of statistics. So sorry for the possible trivialness of the questions. Moreover, i don't yet get everything and maybe, I ve set some hypothesis or constants as obviously shared ideas whereas it wasn't. So please free to ask if i forgot anything. Thank you.

Comment: I've replaced your newly-created [tag:exponential-familly] with the existing [tag:exponential-distribution], although I'm not entirely sure it's appropriate as it's out of my area of expertise. If you really want to create [tag:exponential-family], it's better to first "test the waters" by posting in the [Tag management thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019). You can also discuss this in the [Tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/tagging).

Comment: Ok sorry didn't know how to proceed. However this new tag is not at all related to my post. I ll test the water as you said but for now i delete the tag

Comment: I found the answer but I'm too lazy to write it down. If anyone needs it one day, write a comment and i'll help you out.